# modal not opening react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function to open my modal that activates based on a prop function that I have passed to my Body component that changes a state in my main class App and when I click the anchor I have placed in the toggle menu it opens the modal however I am trying to make a demo that runs the code automatically. The demo function is inside my Body component When I run the demo function, it opens the menu but does not open my notes modal.

the function also outputs the correct value when running from the demo, the modal just does not pop up.

```
//I have the following state:

this.state={
  showNotes: false

//this function changes the state
openNotes = () =>{
      console.log("opening notes")
      this.setState({showNotes:!this.state.showNotes})
  }

//I pass this function as a prop to my body component
  <Route path="/app" render ={props=><Body {...props} openNotes={this.openNotes} />}/>


//inside body I use this function to create a demo of everything in the app. 


rundemo=()=>{
  console.log("run the demo")
  let counter=0
    console.log("begin the wait")
  while (counter < 10000){
    counter+=1
    console.log(counter)
  }

  counter=0
  this.props.setHighlightMode()
  while (counter < 10000){
    counter+=1
  }

  var docvalue= document.getElementById('regex-example').value
  var selection = this.range(0,20,docvalue)//get selected chars in element

  console.log("document value",docvalue)
  console.log("selection in range",selection)
  var selectedText = selection.toString(); //sends the elements to a string
  console.log("selection text to update",selectedText)
  {this.props.updateHighlight(selectedText)} //send highlight to main to send to notes


  while (counter < 10000){
    counter+=1
  }
  this.props.setHighlightMode()
  counter=0
  while (counter < 10000){
    counter+=1
  }
    this.props.toggleMenu()
    while (counter < 10000){
      counter+=1
    }

this.props.openNotes()
  counter=0
  while (counter < 10000){
    counter+=1
  }

  counter=0
  while (counter < 10000){
    counter+=1
  }
  this.props.close()
  counter=0
  this.props.setScholarMode()
  this.props.DemosynonymsFunction(selectedText.toString())
  console.log("next return a synonym")
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. Can you elaborate more? Can you post complete flow.

Comment: certainly, I have edited my original post for clarity